# Dual Channel Opus Encoding

Tags: c++, encode, opus

I have been using the opus library for a while now, mostly using mono channel audio. However, I have been working on dual channel audio and have been trying to get it to work with opus. I initially thought it would be pretty straight forward, because I'd just be increasing the number of channels in the `opus_encoder_create` function, and increasing my frame_size in the `opus_encode` function. However, when I do encode the audio, all I get out is a jumbled mess, of what appears to be a summation of the two waveforms. The input is PCM data, interleaved by each sample (L1, R1, L2, R2, .. LN, RN). I am unsure how to proceed, any advice, or sample code would be appreciated.

So far, I have tried supplying the data as (L1, L2,.. LN, R1, R2, ... RN) and when I do it as such, the audio is intelligible, but the two channels are still corrupted, and I don't believe that this is the correct approach.

Here is a sample of how I am doing the conversion

```
#define NUM_CHANNELS 2
#define SAMPLE_RATE 8000
#define FRAME_SIZE 960
#define OUTPUT_FRAME_BYTES FRAME_SIZE / 8

int main(void) {
    int err;
    OpusEncoder *encoder;

    int16_t pcm_data[FRAME_SIZE * NUM_CHANNELS];
    uint8_t compressed_data[OUTPUT_FRAME_BYTES * NUM_CHANNELS];

    while (true) {
        /* Gather Dual Channel PCM Data from Microphone, and interleave
            pcm_data[0] = left channel sample 1
            pcm_data[1] = right channel sample 1
            pcm_data[2] = left channel sample 2
            pcm_data[3] = right channel sample 2
            ...
            pcm_data[FRAME_SIZE * NUM_CHANNELS - 2] = left channel sample FRAME_SIZE
            pcm_data[FRAME_SIZE * NUM_CHANNELS - 1] = right channel sample FRAME_SIZE
         */

        encoder =
            opus_encoder_create(8000, NUM_CHANNELS, OPUS_APPLICATION_RESTRICTED_LOWDELAY, &err);

        opus_encoder_ctl(encoder, OPUS_SET_COMPLEXITY(0));

        opus_encode(encoder, pcm_data, FRAME_SIZE, compressed_data,
                    OUTPUT_FRAME_BYTES * NUM_CHANNELS);

        // Write compressed data to file
        opus_encoder_destroy(encoder);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot help you due to a lack of familiarly with opus, but I have a recommendation that should help strengthen the question and make it more likely to get answers: Add a small example program, a [mre], that demonstrates how you are trying to use opus and fails as you describe. This helps us see where you are and tailor answers to better fit your needs. For all anyone knows, you could have a tiny mistake or misunderstanding that can be cleared up in seconds by an experienced opus user. Or maybe you have a problem that requires the attentions of an opus guru. Right now it's hard to tell.

Comment: Please post a [mre] that we can test and debug ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, I just added an example, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have incorrect `FRAME_SIZE`. [Official documentation](https://opus-codec.org/docs/opus_api-1.3.1/group__opus__encoder.html) says:

> To encode a frame, opus_encode() or opus_encode_float() must be called with exactly one frame (2.5, 5, 10, 20, 40 or 60 ms) of audio data

Frame size can be calculated as `frameSize = frameLength * sampleRate / 1000` where `frameLength` is in ms. So you should have frame size from 20 (for 2.5 ms) to 480 (for 60 ms).

Another thing - your `compressed_data` size shouldn't depend on `FRAME_SIZE`, at the link above you can find suggested size for the output payload:

> 4000 bytes is recommended